# The difference between '--max-args' and '--max-replace-args' in GNU Parallel?

Tags: gnu-parallel

According to the manual of GNU parallel, the difference between `--max-args / -n` and `--max-replace-args / -N`, is that the latter is **Like -n but also makes
replacement strings {1} .. {max-args} that represents argument 1 .. max-args.**

```
--max-replace-args=max-args
-N max-args
    Use at most max-args arguments per command line. Like -n but also makes
    replacement strings {1} .. {max-args} that represents argument 1 .. max-args.
```

What does that actually mean? Does it mean that `--max-args / -n` would NOT interpret replacement strings `{1}` .. `{max-args}`? But the following test shows that the replacement strings `{1} {2} {3}` could be interpreted correctly:

```
$ parallel -n3 echo {3} {2} {1} ::: {A..F}
C B A
F E D

$ parallel -N3 echo {3} {2} {1} ::: {A..F}
C B A
F E D
```

So what's really the difference between the two?

Comment: I tried looking at the [source code](https://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=parallel) (written in Perl) a bit but still couldn't figure it out. `{1}` also seems to work with `-L` and `-l`. Here is a really [out of date clone if you want to browse on GitHub](https://github.com/martinda/gnu-parallel/blob/master/src/parallel). I also see `-m`, `-X`, `--xargs` affects whether `$Global::ContextReplace` is on. Not sure what context replace does but it doesn't seem to the `{1}` feature. I think I'm just gonna stick with using `-N` since that's exactly what I need based on docs.

Comment: The only difference between [`-n` and `-N`](https://github.com/martinda/gnu-parallel/blob/master/src/parallel#L791-L792) is that [`-N` has `$Global::ContextReplace = 1`](https://github.com/martinda/gnu-parallel/blob/master/src/parallel#L992-L995) while [`-n` doesn't](https://github.com/martinda/gnu-parallel/blob/master/src/parallel#L888).

Comment: You can see that [`-L` also sets `$Global::max_number_of_args` when `--pipe` is off](https://github.com/martinda/gnu-parallel/blob/master/src/parallel#L985-L991). You can skip setting [`$Global::ContextReplace = 1`](https://github.com/martinda/gnu-parallel/blob/master/src/parallel#L996-L1000) if [`--xargs` or `-m` is set](https://github.com/martinda/gnu-parallel/blob/master/src/parallel#L996-L1000). But `parallel --dry-run -L 2 -m echo {1} ::: 1 2` and `parallel --dry-run -L 2 --xargs echo {1} ::: 1 2` still correctly select the first argument. Seems like `{1}` argument selection is always on.

Comment: @dosentmatter I remember once looking into the source and it didn't reveal anything for me either, nevertheless thank you for looking into this :D